# How to put html image in a ruby value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I am trying to insert an HTML image to be at the very beginning of this string here.

```
content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: ('Greetings ' + @lead.name + ',
       
       ' 'We thank you for contacting Rocket Elevators to discuss the opportunity to contribute to your project ' + @lead.project_name + '.

       A representative from our team will be in touch with you very soon. We look forward to demonstrating the value of our solutions and helping you choose the appropriate product given your requirements.
   
       We’ll Talk soon
       
       The Rocket Team
       '))
```

What should I do? I am using Ruby on rails, and this is for an automated email.

Comment: Well you can't send an image in a Plain Text email so that would be where I would start. Otherwise there is not a lot to go on here.

Comment: There are several ways to include an image in your email. This blog post discusses the different techniques: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/  If you let us know which technique you want to use, we can be more specific in how to do that, though the CID technique is really the one that would require any use of code.  The other two options are pretty vanilla HTML techniques.